# Rails - Good way to associate units of measurement with my database columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got one model with about 50 columns of measurement data, each with a different unit of measurement (ie. grams, ounces, etc.). What is a good way to associate units of measurement with columns in my database? The primary use for this is simply for display purposes. (Ruby on Rails)

EDIT: To clarify, my model is an object, and the attributes are different measurements of that object. So, an example would be if I had the model `Car` and the attribute columns `:power`, `:torque`, `:weight`, `:wheelbase`, etc. I would want `car.power.unit` to return `hp` and `car.weight.unit` to return `lbs.`, etc. This way, I would be able to do something like this:

```
<%= car.power + car.power.unit %>
```

and it would return

```
400hp
```

Comment: Do your columns ever end up with different units? Ie do you sometimes have "power" in horsepower and sometimes in watts, or is each column always one unit type?

Comment: @Andrew - For now, only one unit type is necessary. That may be implemented in future iterations, but for the purposes of this question, no conversions will need to be done.

Comment: Cant you add a table with the units and add columns like "torque_unit" to the messurements-table, where you save the id of the unit? This would make it easy to deal with different units for the same attribute. In the unit model you could have all the between-unit-converting methods, if you ever need those...

Comment: @klump - I'm not sure I follow your suggestion. Each individual attribute has the same unit regardless of the object. For example, all `Car` objects will have a unit of `lb-ft.` for `car.torque`. The only times the units differ is between attributes, such as between `car.torque` and `car.power`.

Comment: I updated my answer, but I do not find it so useful, I would prefer the decorator-method by Andrew...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Since you're storing many columns of data, but each column is only one type, and your concern is strictly presentational, I would just use a decorator to accomplish what you need. See this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper) for an example of a great way to do this using [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper).

Basically, a decorator wraps your model with presentation specific methods, so instead of:

```
#CarsController.rb
def show
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
end
```

You would use

```
#CarsController.rb
def show
  @car = CarDecorator.find(params[:id])
end
```

You would define a decorator like so:

```
class CarDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  decorates :car

  def horsepower
    model.power.to_s + "hp" #call to_s just in case
  end

end
```

Then in your view any time you called `@car.horsepower` you would get `123hp` instead of `123`. In this way you can build a big long reusable list of presentation methods. You can share methods between objects using inheritance, and you can allow methods from the original model to be called as well. See the railscast and the docs etc. You can use Draper or you could roll your own presenter class if you don't want to use a library.

---

Previous Answer (Abridged):

I can see two nice, easy ways to do this:

1) Just add a text column for `units` to your data model. IE: to get "400hp" use `[data.value,data.units].join`

2) You could get a little richer association by having a `Units` model, perhaps with help from something like [ActiveEnum](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum).

Comment: Looks promising - I'll give it a shot and confirm if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a unit model with a `for` attribute, where you save the attribute in the messurement, you want to apply the unit to. Example:

```
def Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for, lambda{|messurement| find_by_for( messurement.to_s ) }
end
```

This allows you stuff like:

```
<%= @car.torque + Unit.for(:torque).symbol %>
```

I do not know if this is of so much advantage, but its a way to solve your problem...

Comment: See my new edits on the main question - I have one model with many attribute columns of measurement.